# SQL Search using a pattern

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want search a number which has a pattern, e.g. 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 111, 122 - i.e., two digits are repeating

Comment: Sounds perfect for a regular expression. Or I guess you could use 10 `like` statements...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has it's own REGEXP function that you should be able to use pretty easily. [[doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)]

Once you've got how that syntax works, this regex will get you what you need.

```
(\d)\1
```

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP can do this really well.

```
'[0-9]{2,}'
```

match if a digit between 0 and 9 is repeated at least 2 times.